# asp.net MVC cascading dropdownlist returns undefined using ajax

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu, undefined, cascading

Im trying to make a cascading dropdown list for Classes and Subjects, when I select a Class from the dropdown list the subject Dropdown shows subjects that are in the responding Class.
But the subject value that is returned in the controller is (Undefined)

**Here is my view**

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PDFClass, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PDFClass, ViewBag.ClassName as SelectList, "Please Select", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PDFClass, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
           
        </div>
    </div>




    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PDFSubject, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PDFSubject, new SelectList(" "), "Please Select", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PDFSubject, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            
        </div>
    </div>
```

**here is the Ajax**

```
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#PDFClass").change(function () {

                $.get("/Home/GetStateList", { Class: $("#PDFClass").val() }, function (data) {
                    $("#PDFSubject").empty();
                    $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                        $("#PDFSubject").append("<option value = '" + row.Class + "'>" + row.SubjectName + "</option>")
                        debugger;
                    });
                });
            })
        });
    </script>
```

**Here is the method that gets a list of Classes&Subjects relation Table to the Ajax**

```
        public JsonResult GetStateList(string Class)
        {

            var List1 = context.ClassesWithSubjects_.ToList().Where(i => i.ClassName == Class);
            return Json(List1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```